# How to create help paper for the own package?

Tags: r

I have created my own package with description file and help paper for every function. 
Now if I code `?mypackage::myfunction` R displays help paper to `myfunction`. But when I code `?mypackage` R displays *"No documentation for ‘mypackage’ in specified packages and libraries:"* :(

Comment: Look at the file structure of your favorite package. It should have `pkgname-package.Rd` file somewhere or it just aliases using `\alias{pkg-package}`. For example, here [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/1f0e268f98eab93c9d5755edbaf9ff978459ce4f/man/data.table.Rd).

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I have created documentation with `roxygen2` and in `man` folder I can see `.Rd` files for function but there  is no such file for the package. So there is no `mypackage.Rd`.

Answer (score 3):

In case you are not using `roxygen2` (but you probably should), you need to create a .Rd file with the general mandatory fields, including a `\docType{package}`. See section 2.1.4 of the [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Documenting-data-sets).

> Apart from the mandatory \name and \title and the pkgname-package
>   alias, the only requirement for the package overview page is that it
>   include a \docType{package} statement. All other content is optional.
>   We suggest that it should be a short overview, to give a reader
>   unfamiliar with the package enough information to get started. More
>   extensive documentation is better placed into a package vignette (see
>   Writing package vignettes) and referenced from this page, or into
>   individual man pages for the functions, datasets, or classes.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using `Roxygen2` to generate your documentation, somewhere you will need something like this saved in a `.R` file.

```
#' Title
#'
#' Description
#'
#' @docType package
#' @name varbinq
NULL
```

This will create a help file for your package that can be accessed when you type `?varbinq`

For more information see [this section](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html#man-packages) of Hadley Wickham's book entitled R Packages.

Comment: assuming Roxygen is being used to generate Rd files

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the roxygen2 package for documenting your package called "mypackage", the [documented way](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/rd.html#documenting-packages) to do this is to write this code in a file named "mypackage.R":

```
#' Generate R documentation from inline comments.
#'
#' Roxygen2 allows you to write documentation in comment blocks co-located
#' with code.
#'
#' The only function you're likely to need from \pkg{roxygen2} is
#' \code{\link{roxygenize}}. Otherwise refer to the vignettes to see
#' how to format the documentation.
"_PACKAGE"
```

You will then be able to retrieve your package's help page using:

```
??mypackage
```

Comment: No, your answer is different. And not as good as mine, in my opinion.

My answer is taken directly from the **current** roxygen2 vignette, includes a link, and mentions the filename. Yours, while it may work is not mentionned in the vignette, is more verbose, does not mention where to save the code, did not have a link until it was edited, and did not mention the roxygen2 dependency until it was edited.